# Same values being returned for multiple rows in sql but not all columns

Tags: sql

i'm currently running the following query (see below.) 
However when i do the same values is returned for multiple rows in totalusers, activeusers and suspendedusers. 
However when it comes to total login the values are unique. 
Is their a reason why this could be happening and is their a way to solve the problem. If it helps im using the tool sql workben with postgre sql driver.

Cheers

```
SELECT
    company.companyStatus,
    company.CompanyId,
    company.companyName,
    select 
        count(distinct UserID) 
        From Users 
            inner join company 
                on Users.CompanyID = Company.CompanyId
        where Users.Companyid = company.Companyid
        as TotalUsers,
    select sum(case when userstatusid =2 then 1 else 0 end)
        from users 
            inner join company 
                on users.companyid = company.companyid
        where users.companyid = company.companyid) 
        as ActiveUsers,
    select sum(case when userstatusid = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
        from users 
            inner join company 
                on users.companyid = company.companyid
        where users.companyid = company.companyid) 
        as SuspendedUsers,
    (Select COUNT (distinct usersessionid)
    From UserSession 
        inner join users  
                on usersession.UserID=users.UserID
    where usersession.UserID=users.UserID  
        and users.companyid= company.CompanyID) 
        as TotalLogin,
from  Company
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  It does not seem unusual for some columns to return duplicates when other columns return unique values.  This would just imply that you have more values from one of your subqueries for each of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your TotalUsers, ActiveUsers and SuspendedUsers queries are all using their own (unrestricted) copy of the Company table, whereas your TotalLogin is using the main instance from which you're selecting. This means that the TotalLogin numbers you're seeing are for that particular company, but the other fields are across ALL companies.

Presumably you wanted something more like:

```
   SELECT 
   company.companyStatus,
   company.CompanyId,
   company.companyName,
   count(distinct u.UserID) TotalUsers,
   sum(case when u.userstatusid =2 then 1 else 0 end) ActiveUsers,
   sum(case when u.userstatusid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) SuspendedUsers,
   count(distinct u.usersessionid) TotalLogin
   from  Company 
   inner join Users on Users.CompanyID = Company.CompanyId
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you have `company` in the subqueries for those calculations.

I much prefer having table references in the `from` clause where possible, and you can write this query moving everything to the `from` clause:

```
   SELECT c.companyStatus, c.CompanyId, c.companyName,
          uc.Totalusers, uc.Activeusers, uc.Suspendedusers, ucs.TotalLogin
   from  Company c left outer join
         (select u.companyid,
                 COUNT(distinct userid) as Totalusers,
                 SUM(case when userstatusid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as ActiveUsers,
                 sum(case when userstatusid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as Suspendedusers
          from users u
          group by u.companyid
         ) uc
         uc.companyid = c.companyId left outer join
         (select u.companyid, COUNT(distinct usersessionid) as TotalLogin
          from UserSession us inner join
               users u
               on us.UserID = u.UserID
         ) ucs
         on ucs.companyid = c.companyid;
```

This should also speed up the query because it doesn't have to do the same work multiple times.